# Symfony2: overriding Sensio FrameworkExtraBundle template guesser

Tags: symfony

I am trying to override the standard template guesser ( located in Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Templating; ) becouse I want to use annotations to set the view but need to change the logic of how the actual view file is chosen.

I have seen this: https://github.com/elnur/ElnurTemplateGuesserBundle
but I was wondering if there is a way to just override the service in configuration.

I tried setting:

```
services:
    sensio_framework_extra.view.guesser:
        class: myCompany\myBundle\Templating\TemplateGuesser
```

but I get:

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: 
Argument 1 passed to Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Templating\TemplateGuesser::__construct()  
must implement interface Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface, none given
```

Am I supposed to set an argument in the service config setting? But how do I reference the HttpKernel?
Or am I missing something?
TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the kernel the [same way the as the original TemplateGuesser](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.xml#L13). The name of the Kernel service is just simply `kernel`.

```
services:
    sensio_framework_extra.view.guesser:
        class:     myCompany\myBundle\Templating\TemplateGuesser
        arguments: [ "@kernel" ]
```

To see a full list of services in the container, run

```
$ php app/console container:debug
```

Of which you'll see the `kernel` listed as one of them.

Comment: perfect... thank you! I wonder, is there a documentation page for this? I would I go about finding that out for myself(besides the source code)? I looked here before asking: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html but @kernel is not there.

Comment: Good question. I usually run `php app/console container:debug` which will list all the services in the container, the class of the service and the scope of the service.